# Calling the current closure from within a closure

Tags: php, closures, anonymous-function

In javascript, you can do something like this

```
arr.map(function(val) {
    return typeof val == 'array' ? val.map(arguments.callee) : val.doSomething();
});
```

This will iterate recursively through `arr` and apply `doSomething` to each value.

**Is there an equivalent to JavaScript's arguments.callee in PHP?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Is there an equivalent to JavaScript's arguments.callee in PHP?

You'd have to pass the function to itself:

```
$func = function($a = 0) use (&$func) {
    echo "$a\n";
    if ($a == 1) {
        return;
    }
    $func(1);
};

$func();

/* output:
0
1
*/
```

Comment: This is good. The downside is that the function must be assigned to a variable.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe there is an equivalent to arguments.callee. If you really want a recursive lambda in php, there is always the y combinator pattern: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed-point_combinator#Y_combinator

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly as requested, but probably more appropriate:

```
array_walk_recursive($arr, function (&$val) {
    $val = doSomething($val);
});
```